# ArrayUtils.removeElement vs. ArrayUtils.remove

Tags: java, arrays

What is the difference between

> ArrayUtils.removeElement

and

> ArrayUtils.remove

?

Comment: Have you read [the javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) ? It is pretty clearly explained...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to this question could be found by simply checking the JavaDoc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html),

## remove:

```
Removes the element at the specified position from the specified array.
```

#### example:

```
ArrayUtils.remove(['a'], 0)           = []
ArrayUtils.remove(['a', 'b'], 0)      = ['b']
ArrayUtils.remove(['a', 'b'], 1)      = ['a']
ArrayUtils.remove(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1) = ['a', 'c']
```

## removeElement:

```
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from the specified array.
```

#### example:

```
ArrayUtils.removeElement(null, 'a')            = null
ArrayUtils.removeElement([], 'a')              = []
ArrayUtils.removeElement(['a'], 'b')           = ['a']
ArrayUtils.removeElement(['a', 'b'], 'a')      = ['b']
ArrayUtils.removeElement(['a', 'b', 'a'], 'a') = ['b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayUtils.removeElement removes the first occurrence of the specified element from the specified array.

ArrayUtils.remove removes the element at the specified position from the specified array.

Please refer: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html